# Styling select not displaying the same on Chrome or Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem styling a select box with Chrome and Safari, on Firefox works fine.

[image: Firefox !]

[image: Chrome and Safari]

```css
.first-selects {
  width: 184px;
  height: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(../images/select.png) no-repeat right #fff;
  border: 1px solid #9ca4ab;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.first-selects select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 204px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 24px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #686868;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-selects">
  <select id="idcategory">
    <option value="-1">Category</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I'm really don't know why they look so different on Chrome/Safari versus Firefox

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? My copy (39) doesn't style your select box at all.

Comment: I'm using 39.0.2171.99

Comment: Same here (but Linux; guessing you're OSX). Does the Run Code Snippet button in your question style it for you? If so, looks like the styling is still experimental and probably worth avoiding for now (odds are almost none that it works on IE anyway)

Comment: Doesn't work  the Run Code Snippet for me neither . The problem was with line-height property.. It was set to 44px instead to 24px to match the height as suggested by @jmore009

Comment: @Dave Now the Code snippet works perfect. The problem was with the class of the div it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your `line-height` set it equal to the `select`s height:

```
.first-selects select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 204px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px; //change to 24px to match the height
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #686868;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cL18q8rh/)

FYI you have a typo in the script you posted above:

```
<div class="firt-selects">
```

should be:

```
<div class="first-selects">
```

Comment: You've got two `line-height` rules.

Comment: The problem was with the line-height set to 44px instead to match the height of the select. About the typo sorry i just write the html code didn't copy it from my code

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 line-height statements in .first-selects select.

Comment: Thats not an issue (although it's obviously not good to have multiple declerations of the same property), the second one will just override the first

Comment: Correct, but OP probably didn't notice the second line-height declaration which caused the problem in the first place. Since your answer didn't mention it, I figured adding it here to make sure OP noticed the second declaration. (Can't comment on other answers yet.)